# Access to OpenAM svn server

Tags: svn, repository, openam

I have a problem accessing OpenAM SVN repository using Subclipse and was hoping that someone could give me a clue what can be wrong here. From documentation ([link](https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Guide+to+OpenAM+Subversion)) I copied a link (https://svn.forgerock.org/openam/trunk/opensso/) and pasted it into Subclipse's SVN Repository location uri field. After waiting a while I've got an error:

RA layer request failed
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.forgerock.org/openam/trunk/opensso': could not connect to server (https://svn.forgerock.org)

I can access the svn url in my browser using given link, but cannot do it through eclipse/subclipse.

Any idea how can I grab those sources or where the problem could be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`could not connect to server` indicates either a temporary connection error (like you or the server not being connected to the internet) or a misconfigured svn server. In a console, try

```
ping svn.forgerock.org
```

If this results in an error message, your connection is somehow impeded. If you can't checkout other public repositories, it's likely a firewall (typically coupled with an HTTP proxy for your browser). If you can checkout other repositories, the server may just be down at the moment; try pinging from another machine.

Comment: You was right, can't connect to other repositories as well and other machine inside our network couldn't do it either.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely,  your svn client needs to trust the certificate presented by the svn.forgerock.org svn server.

Have you tried it manually using the svn command line?

Allan Foster
Forgerock the home of OpenAM
www.forgerock.com